# Python pipe input() to eval function / python console to retrieve data on crash or caught exception

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a long running python data script (days) that is quite complicated (uses mqtt and has multiple agents connected). I can handle/catch when a device or other component disconnects, thus I can pause the script at this stage with a loop. Until i investigate & fix the agent. However it would be better if I could jump to python's input() command, but I would like all of these inputs to be evaluated to the python internal variables so I could print & inspect vars / run a function etc before continuing.

This is the equivalent of running in debug mode in an IDE like pycharm and running the evaluate command before resuming. Before you ask - no I cannot easily restart the script without starting from the beginning. Here is my attempt.

```
def error_debug():
    while 1:
        try:
            r=input("Program crashed, try: RESUME, RESCAN, or CONSOLE \n >")
            if r.upper() == "RESUME":
                return
            elif r.upper() == "RESCAN":
                rescan()
            elif r.upper() == "CONSOLE":
                # direct output to console
                while 1:
                    eval(input('>>>'))

        except KeyboardInterrupt as ke:
            return
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

Whilst this runs, the eval() function doesn't appear to let me type as if I were in console. Can I make a poor mans console with just input?

Comment: You need `exec`, not `eval`.

Comment: There is the `code` module for making a REPL.